# Disable error reporting php 5.6 Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I have become a webmaster on an old forum and inherited a major problem.
Basically we get error logs approx 750mb every day like this, and within days our domain is full.

> [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/loader.php on line 71
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 32
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/loader.php on line 71
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/loader.php on line 161
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/loader.php on line 138
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 33
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 463
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 464
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 465
>   [21-Aug-2018 06:17:50 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/xx/public_html/xx/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 466*

So far I have tried to add php_flag display_errors Off to the .htaccess and it gave me a 500 warning when trying to load the web site

We have Joomla 1.5.26 and php 5.6

Would it be a case of rolling back to php 5.4 or do I add some code to the 5.6 php.ini file
Incidentally its named php.ini2 ????

Sorry for my inexperience but I am trying my best to sort this.
Thanks
Terry

Comment: Have you tried to change php.ini?

Comment: Had a similiar problem, if like me the host disables all attempts to amend PHP parameters from `.htaccess` your only option is to rollback to, probably PHP5.3

Comment: Not tried to change php yet. weirdly it does not have error_reporting = , only the examples prefixed by ; What about the ini2?

Comment: It's better to ask Joomla related questions on [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/). You may need to think about upgrading to the latest version of Joomla. It can be difficult and time-consuming, but it is worth it. Joomla 1.5 is not secure!

Comment: Yes , that wil be for later, just have to stop these errors at the moment. Cheers

Comment: Update to a supported version of Joomla. Joomla 1.5 is ancient, and does not support current versions of PHP.

Comment: Now sorted. Got the hoster to roll back the PHP as I couldn't as their server couldn't take older version.

Comment: Yikes, this is a cringe-worthy solution.  I will hope and pray that you are going to make upgrading the PHP and the Joomla versions a top-level priority -- for many reasons, but mostly security.